# Youtube Iframe on Angular2

Tags: angular, iframe, youtube

I m trying to to add a Youtube Iframe inside Angular2 app. If I put the url in the iFrame everything works ok:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/wzrnuUOoFNM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

But if I try to fetch the URL from the server, with a subscription on the OnInit method in the component, like this,

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/{{video.id}}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

The video is not displayed and the console shows this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property stack of [object Object] which has only a getter
```

I think that it is related with the time of the app to take the data from the server. When the page loads there is no `{{video.id}}` because is not ready yet, but when is ready for any reason the iframe is not updated.

Any ideas to solve this?

Comment: Hi Joel, thanks for your response. I have already the ngIf covering the iframe.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the  [DomSanitizer](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform-browser/index/DomSanitizer-class.html) to pass the Angular's built-in sanitization.

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `    
    <iframe width="560" height="315" [src]="url" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  video: any = {id: 'wzrnuUOoFNM'};
  baseUrl:string = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/';
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { 
    this.url = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.baseUrl + this.video.id);    
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm!. I would like to say that I do the sanitization when I receive the data from the server, i.e., at the subscription.

Comment: @TIIUNDER this is a full component code, you place the code in your component, I don't get your question.